# how-to a cakephp 2.0 model without database table?

Tags: cakephp-2.0

How to retrieve data from model with $useTable = false

i tried, actually, it doesnt work.

```
class Blablah extends AppModel {
   public $useTable = false;
   public $data = array(
           array( "id"=>0, "fied1" => "bla", "field2" =>"blah"), ...
   );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is already a [pretty good answer on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10049567/what-can-i-put-in-schema-model-field-to-build-a-custom-tableless-model) here on StackOverflow.

You should also checkout [different datasources](https://github.com/cakephp/datasources/tree/master/models/datasources) - it might be just what you're looking for. I would use `array_source` for what you need.

Answer (score 0):

In the controller action, you can load the required model and access its data as:

> ```
> $this->loadModel('Blablah');
> debug($this->Blablah->data);
> ```